# Unable to pass query parameter in http call flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 final body = {"Status": status};
final uri =
    Uri.http(EndpointsUrl.baseUrlURi, EndpointsUrl.appoinment,body);
```

I  tried to pass the query parameter in the above code, but I got

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"message": "Status Cannot be undefined.",
"error": "Bad Request"
```

}

Somebody please guide how to pass query params in HTTP get call-in flutter

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
    var uri = Uri.parse('http://www.myappserver.com');
    uri = uri.replace(query: 'yourParam=0');
    print(uri);
```

Comment: can i see how exactly you wrote the query?

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters should be added to the end of the url with “?” Symbol I’m not sure what are you trying to do here.